# Sign out of Appstore in Simulator

Tags: ios, testing, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator, storekit

I am testing in app purchases in XCode simulator. I signed into it using one test account. Now I wanted to test it with another account and it is asking me for the password of first account. How can I completely log out of it. I tried by cleaning (Shift + Command + k, Shift + Command + Option + k) and by removing all folders in ~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simultor/6.1/ 
Still no use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please Reset Content and Settings of simulator from top menu and try in again. It will surely sign out from old account.

Comment: If you don't want to do that everytime you can sign out under the "Settings" app